# How can you check if a function is being called In the shell in Python?

Tags: python, function

Make a function that prints a random fact from a list of facts every time it's called.

My Code:

```
import random
def FACT_FUNCTION():
    x = ["Albert Einstien created the theory of relativity","The world record for the one hundred meter dash is nine point five eight seconds","The founder of apple is Steve Jobs","Google's current CEO is Sundar Pichai"]
    s = random.choice(x)
```

I've done everything up to this point but how do
I check if my function has been called. I assume
that the question is asking to see
if a function has been called in the
shell but I am not sure. If anyone
could supply me with a code that would be nice!
Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can certainly have your function read a counter from file, increment it, and write it back.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: The way I interpret that prompt, you have already met the requirements (other than you don't `print(s)`.)

Comment: A function does absolutely nothing except when it is called.  *Anything* you put in the function will happen precisely when the function is called.  Basically, you're over-thinking this - all you need is a `print(s)` in the function.

Comment: what you mean by "function is being called In the shell"? from terminal/cmd you can only run run program not independent functions in that program. run it by command" python3 filename.py" and make the program call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Add print statement to function. Add functioncall to program.

```
import random
def FACT_FUNCTION():
    x = ["Albert Einstien created the theory of relativity","The world record for the one hundred meter dash is nine point five eight seconds","The founder of apple is Steve Jobs","Google's current CEO is Sundar Pichai"]
    s = random.choice(x)
    print(s)
FACT_FUNCTION()
```

save the file with name FACT_FUNCTION.py . Run it in terminal with command:

```
python3 FACT_FUNCTION.py
```

Comment: two things, You don't need to save it with that precise name just in case there was some confusion for the OP, second for windows machines one would have to use `python file_name.py` (notice that there is not that `3`)